# How can I use MySQL to COUNT with a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, count

How can I use MySQL to count with a LEFT JOIN?

I have two tables, sometimes the Ratings table does not have ratings for a photo so I thought LEFT JOIN is needed but I also have a COUNT statement..

**Photos**

```
id  name        src
1   car         bmw.jpg
2   bike        baracuda.jpg
```

**Loves** (picid is foreign key with photos id)

```
id  picid   ratersip
4   1       81.0.0.0
6   1       84.0.0.0
7   2       81.0.0.0
```

Here the user can only rate one image with their IP.

I want to combine the two tables in order of the highest rating. New table

**Combined**

```
id  name    src            picid
1   car     bmw.jpg        1
2   bike    baracuda.jpg   2
```

(bmw is highest rated)

My MySQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM photos 
LEFT JOIN ON photos.id=loves.picid 
ORDER BY COUNT (picid);
```

**My PHP Code: (UPDATED AND ADDED - Working Example...)**

```
$sqlcount = "SELECT p . *
FROM `pics` p
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT `loves`.`picid`, count( 1 ) AS piccount
FROM `loves`
GROUP BY `loves`.`picid`
)l ON p.`id` = l.`picid`
ORDER BY coalesce( l.piccount, 0 ) DESC";

$pics = mysql_query($sqlcount);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Solution above.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid please do **not** add your answer to the question.... Either create a new answer and refer to it in a comment, or don't do it at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL allows you to group by just the `id` column:

```
select
    p.*
from
    photos p 
    left join loves l on
        p.id = l.picid
group by
    p.id
order by
    count(l.picid)
```

That being said, I know MySQL is really bad at `group by`, so you can try putting the `loves` count in a subquery in your join to optimize it:

```
select
    p.*
from
    photos p
    left join (select picid, count(1) as piccount from loves group by picid) l on
        p.id = l.picid
order by
    coalesce(l.piccount, 0)
```

I don't have a MySQL instance to test out which is faster, so test them both.

Comment: The second query worked faster for me. and I added DESC after the last bracket so I could order them by highest to lowest. Thanks. Only issue is no converting for PHP

Comment: Edited, I fixed it. Answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use subqueries:

```
SELECT id, name, src FROM (
  SELECT photos.id, photos.name, photos.src, count(*) as the_count 
  FROM photos 
  LEFT JOIN ON photos.id=loves.picid 
  GROUP BY photos.id
) t 
ORDER BY the_count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
      p.ID,
      p.name,
      p.src,
      PreSum.LoveCount
   from
      Photos p
         left join ( select L.picid,
                            count(*) as LoveCount
                        from
                           Loves L
                        group by
                           L.PicID ) PreSum
           on p.id = PreSum.PicID
   order by
      PreSum.LoveCount DESC
```

Comment: I like the code and indentation on this. So I gave a plus point. Easy to read.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, appreciate it... From the years of writing SQL, so many have such a blur, that it makes it hard for following... The primary "select, from, where, group by, order by, having" are at one level keeping all fields and/or criteria easier to identify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to join the data and do a count(`*`) in your select.  Make sure you specify which table you want to use for ambigous columns.  Also, don't forget to use a group by function when you do a count(*).  Here is an example query that I run on MS SQL.

```
Select CmsAgentInfo.LOGID, LOGNAME, hCmsAgent.SOURCEID, count(*) as COUNT from hCmsAgent
LEFT JOIN CmsAgentInfo on hCmsAgent.logid=CmsAgentInfo.logid
where SPLIT = '990'
GROUP BY CmsAgentInfo.LOGID, LOGNAME, hCmsAgent.SOURCEID
```

The example results form this will be something like this.

```
77615   SMITH, JANE 1   36
29422   DOE, JOHN   1   648
```

Hope that helps.  Good Luck.